# Can a wizard brew a potion of a spell if the spell is higher than a level he can prepare?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, potions

I need clarification of the Brew Potion feat.

As an example, can a 3rd level Wizard copy Heroism into their spellbook by making the appropriate Spellcraft check, even though Heroism is a 3rd level spell, which can not be prepared until the Wizard is 5th level?
**And if so, do they then "know" the spell?**

The PHB states:

> For wizards, knowing a spell means having it in their spellbooks.

And since Brew Potion states:

> You can create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures.

**Can a Heroism potion also be brewed by the 3rd level Wizard?**

Comment: You're asking two different questions here:  one is, "Can I copy a spell into my spellbook if I can't prepare the spell?" and the other question is, "Can I brew a potion of a spell that I know?"  Those two questions have very different answers (yes to the first, not necessarily to the second).  I have edited your question to make the question headline match the content -- please review to ensure I haven't changed the meaning of your question and of course feel free to undo my revision.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes you can have it in your spellbook.

You simply have to have access to the spell and make the requisite Spellcraft check.

> A wizard can also add a spell to her book whenever she encounters one on a magic scroll or in another wizard’s spellbook. No matter what the spell’s source, the wizard must first decipher the magical writing (see Arcane Magical Writings, above). Next, she must spend a day studying the spell. At the end of the day, she must make a Spellcraft check **(DC 15 + spell’s level)**. A wizard who has specialized in a school of spells gains a +2 bonus on the Spellcraft check if the new spell is from her specialty school. She cannot, however, learn any spells from her prohibited schools. If the check succeeds, the wizard understands the spell and can copy it into her spellbook (see Writing a New Spell into a Spellbook, below). The process leaves a spellbook that was copied from unharmed, but a spell successfully copied from a magic scroll disappears from the parchment.

(emphasis mine)

## No you can't brew potions.

Brew potion reads:

> Benefit
>   You can create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures. Brewing a potion takes one day. When you create a potion, you set the caster level, **which must be sufficient to cast the spell in question and no higher than your own level**. The base price of a potion is its spell level × its caster level × 50 gp. To brew a potion, you must spend 1/25 of this base price in XP and use up raw materials costing one half this base price.

(emphasis mine)

Further in the rules for brewing potions:

> **The creator must have prepared the spell** to be placed in the potion (or must know the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any material component or focus the spell requires.

(emphasis mine)

You must have sufficient caster level in order to brew the potion both to set the appropriate caster level and to prepare the spell.

Comment: You already had my +1 but adding the crafting rules really helps to flesh out the answer.  Great jorb.